# Running Script through SNMP commands using SNMP Protocol gives different output as script execute stand alone

Tags: linux, shell, snmp

I want to shell execute a script through `SNMP` command.So for that script i have configured `OID` in `snmpd.conf` under `/etc/snmp` folder.

My script looks like working is just to redirect `"text"` to `output.txt` file and then print script executed on console.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh 

Input_path="$HOME/input.txt"     
Out_Path="$HOME/output.txt"     

#I have to take the line_num from output.txt which is actually number of line present in output.txt 
line_num=`wc -l <$out` 

#after that i need to take that line from INPUT file
line=`head -$a $Input_path | tail -1 ` 

#i need to uppend data to 1 kb for that i am using typset command
typeset -L1024 line 

#I am increasing value of a
a=`expr $a + 1` 

#same i am echo in file so at this point number of line in file will increase by 1
echo $a >> $Out_Path

#this is the final output which i want .
echo -e "$line\n"
```

---

### **Output**

if i am using snmpwalkcommand from node ...1

snmpwalk command the output is

a

and the updated output.txt file is 
1
2

snmpwalk command the output is

c

and the updated output.txt file is 
1
2
3
4

snmpwalk command the output is

c

and the updated output.txt file is 
1
2
3
4
5

### Which means i am getting a,c,e ... but i need a,b,c,d,e

This type of processing i am doing because data is more that 1 kb in output.txt and i am not able to fetch more than 1 kb record in snmpget command, that's why i am doing this process to get whole data.

Answer (score 0):

a) try to include a "shebang" line (`#!/bin/sh`) as very first line of your script

b) try to set full path to your file, like `echo "text" > /tmp/output.txt`

c) be sure that path you write to is writable by UID of snmpd (`/tmp/` usually is)

Comment: I think the issue here is related to buffed operation. Just my guess. Because looks like echo/sed etc commands do buffered read/write which is causing the problem.